# How do you use raw.githubusercontent.com in a GitHub action?

Tags: github, github-actions

I am using a GitHub action in a repo and at one point I want to use a URL to a file in another repo but in the same account.

I thought I could use the URL `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/<username>/<repo>/<branch>/<filename>?token=GITHUB_TOKEN` with the `GITHUB_TOKEN` environment variable for the token but it does not work.

Comment: You shouldn't need a token to access a raw file. First try getting the right link in your browser, then try accessing the same link from the Action. I can't give more specific help because "it does not work" doesn't give any specific details.

Comment: If the token is invalid you will get 404 Not Found.

Comment: It works if I set the repository the URL links to as public instead of private. Maybe you can only do it with a private repository if you have a paid account?

Answer (score 0):

For private repos make a GET request to `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/<username>/<repo>/<branch>/<filename>` and with Header: "Authorization: token yourgithubpersonalaccesstoken".

It seems in the [past](https://developer.github.com/changes/2020-02-10-deprecating-auth-through-query-param/) the query-param solution you mention used to work. Also I've seen mention of `https://yourgithubpersonalaccesstoken@raw.etc`. These no longer work though.